# Joomla updates table error

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, xampp

There is some unusual functioning of my Joomla site. Sometime when I visit the admin dashboard I face this screen
[image]

```
Table 'joomla.z3djq_updates' doesn't exist SQL=SELECT * FROM `z3djq_updates` WHERE `extension_id` > 0 AND `detailsurl` LIKE '........'
```

I have to delete two files in the folder XAMPP->MySQL->data->Joomla folder

1. z3djq_updates.frm
2. z3djq_updates.ibd

Then I run this command

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `z3djq_updates`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `z3djq_updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT 0,
  `version` varchar(32) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  `extra_query` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates';
```

I fail to understand why do I have to repeat this step when neither I am screwing any Joomla component or hacking any core files. What causes this issue. By the way I am on Windows 10 and using XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after copying a database directory directly using command

The issue is that you need the `ib*` files in the root of the MySQL datadir (e.g. `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`).

When I copied those it worked for me.

**IF** this works for you, then these files are getting corrupted somehow.